# Cloud functions throws error after migrating Angular Universal firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-universal

I have a SPA which is hosted in Firebase and I have been using Firestore to store the data. I am also making use of cloud functions for few of my https operations and certain other database read and write.

Recently I updated my rendering logic from client side to server side with angular universal which is pretty successful. Here's the link I followed: https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/

Basically, I had created a https function to render ssr in cloud functions.

```
const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server`).app;
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app); //Application related endpoint line makepayment, createorder etc.,
exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

Now, once I deploy this function, all the `api https` function, where I used to access `db.collection`
or `db.doc` started throwing error. Below is the same call for `db.doc`.

```
db.doc("samplecollection/docid")
.get()
.then(function (doc) {
   console.log('doc.data', doc.data());
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.log('Error in fetching samplecollection doc', error);
});
```

Now when I try to do above I get the below error.

```
Error in autogenerated TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path"
 argument must be of type string. Received type object
      at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
      at Object.basename (path.js:744:5)
      at GrpcClient.loadProto (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\google-gax\build\src\grpc.js:133:29)
      at new FirestoreClient (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\v1\firestore_client.js:121:32)
      at ClientPool.Firestore._clientPool.pool_1.ClientPool [as clientFactory]
 (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:302:26)
      at ClientPool.acquire (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\pool.js:67:35)
      at ClientPool.run (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\pool.js:124:29)
      at Firestore.readStream (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:947:26)
      at Firestore.getAll_ (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:680:14)
      at initializeIfNeeded.then (sampleproject\functions\node_modules\@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\index.js:650:61)
      at ZoneDelegate.invoke (sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:5715:30)
      at Zone.run (sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:5472:47)
      at sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:6213:38
      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:5750:35)
      at Zone.runTask (sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:5517:51)
      at drainMicroTaskQueue (sampleproject\functions\dist\server.js:5930:39)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I am not really sure why the error says *The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object*. I tried to assign path of document to a variable and check its type with `typeof`, it still says as `string`.

Key point to note is - if I remove `ssr`, function and `dist` folder copied into `functions` directory, everything with same line of code works properly. So, I strongly suspect, this has something to do with SSR.

I made a lot of google search for this but none of them had this set-up of SSR.
Could someone please point me in right direction or let me know if anyone has faced this issue with Angular Universal SSR and found a solution?

---

**Update - 1**

I have the below option set in `webpack.server.config.js` file. Will that be a problem?

```
node: {
    __dirname: false
},
```

**Update - 2**

Here's the firebase.json configured for development and production environment.

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "dist/browser",
      "target": "staging",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr"
        }
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|css?*|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
              "value": "*"
            },
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=31536000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "404",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=7200"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "public": "dist",
      "target": "production",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "include": ["**/views/**"]
  }
}
```

Right now, I have just configured this in `staging` i.e. [development environment] for testing, but this issue affects even production environment since cloud functions will remain same for both.

**Update - 3**

Upon further investigation, I noticed that the **firestore_client.js** present within `node_modules` of `functions` dependencies, under the path `node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1` has below piece of code to identify whether its a browser or not.

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
if (isBrowser) {
    opts.fallback = true;
}
.....
.....
.....
// Load the applicable protos.
// For Node.js, pass the path to JSON proto file.
// For browsers, pass the JSON content.
const nodejsProtoPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'protos', 'protos.json');
const protos = gaxGrpc.loadProto(opts.fallback ? require('../../protos/protos.json') : nodejsProtoPath);
```

So the `firestore_client.js` identifies whether this is a browser or not by checking whether the `typeof window !== undefined`. But, in my `server.ts` of my SPA, I have defined `global['window'] = win` from `domino` library. This was added because it would throw **`window is not defined` ReferenceError.**

Basically, that means, the `firestore_client.js` is able to determine `window` object via the `server.js`, generated and kept within `functions` folder and hence it passes `protos.json` file content which is an object, instead of the path. Reading the comments above written in the said file, I feel that a path to the file should be passed here instead of the object for the nodejs environment.

Any idea, how I can overcome this now?

Comment: I don't know how to solve this specific error, but I tried SSR with firebase cloud functions and got some other errors that I could not solve. If using appengine would be an option for you, then I would go for it (https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/)

Comment: @michelepatrassi.. Not really sure, if that is a good option. Never went on trying that and also, worried about the pricing, since our project is on the flame plan as of now. This might prove us costly.

Comment: How does your `firebase.json` look like? do you have a `"source"` as project root dir specified?

Comment: @Vojtech.. Updated my question. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: I checked with my config and you don't seem to have the `source` in `functions` config, try adding `"source": "folderName"` where folder name will be the name of the folder your cloud function is in relative to a `firebase.json`

Comment: @Vojtech something like `source:functions`?

Comment: My `firebase.json` looks like this 

`{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
   ...
  } }
`

Comment: @Vojtech Tried your suggestion but still, I am getting the same error. Here's how my firebase.json looks like now - `"functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "include": ["**/views/**"]
  }`

Comment: @Vojtech.. For some reason, the `path` library under the functions `node_modules` isn't able to resolve the necessary `path` for `protos.json` under `firestore_client.json`. That's where this error is been seen.

This comment in `firestore_client.js` makes me feel that instead of `node`, the function is trying to run in `browser` assuming it the env as browser - `// Load the applicable protos.
        // For Node.js, pass the path to JSON proto file.
        // For browsers, pass the JSON content.` Below this is the `gaxGrpc.loadProto` method which throws the error.

Comment: Do you have a babel config?

Comment: @SreeramPadmanabhan Nope.. I don't have one..

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-345228799. IMHO you need to find the way to imitate the browser on your server side. The comment looks related to that point

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer you are hoping for, but posting it anyway.

A while ago I tried basically the same. I used Firebase authentication and Realtime Database instead of Firestore. Also, I used AngularFire2. I'm not sure if you are using this as well. The build was fine, however I'd always get runtime exceptions.

I found multiple statements claiming Firebase authentication and realtime datebase could not work with ssr since it depends on some browser functionality. Unfortunately I can't find them now. Not sure if this is firebase related or AngularFire related.

I search for multiple tutorial/posts about ssr combined with realtime database. I couldn't find any but one. [This](https://medium.com/@hamedbaatour/angular-5-server-side-rendering-with-firebase-step-by-step-guide-ec5f4d8ef38b) guide explains how to use Firestore with SSR. The difference is they are using [AngularFireLite](https://github.com/hamedbaatour/angularfire-lite) instead of AngularFire.

Comment: Might not be the case, because this one's typically related to the SSR application interfering with cloud functions and making functions believe that they are running in browser instead of node.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this library - AngularFireLite - But tell me one thing, is it maintained? It was last updated on Jul 16, 2019. Will it support Angular 8? The last update as I've seen from the commit is, it supports Angular 6. So, can this be trusted? :)

Comment: Tbh I wouldn't know. I had the same concerns. SSR wasn't a big deal for be so I didn't try it. The `package.json` refers to angular 8.1.1 so I guess it works fine with angular 8. Though it hasn't that many comments, neither has AngularFire (Note not AngularFireLite) which is maintained by the angular team. So I guess it is just not that complex.

Answer (score 2):

So I've got 2 options that I'm gonna throw out there, hoping one of them will work.

1. try an older version:
   uninstall current installation:

> ```
> npm uninstall @angular/fire firebase --save
> ```

then install the older version, I did below:

> ```
> npm install @angular/fire@5.0.0 firebase@5.9.0 --save
> ```

2. Not sure if you have this in your webpack.server.config:

> ```
> module.exports = {
> ...
>  resolve: {
>     alias: {
>       ['firebase/app']: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/firebase/app/dist/index.cjs.js')
>     }
>   }
> ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi @Shlomo, definitely let me try this approach tomorrow and will let you know. 2nd approach looks promising, as I don't have it as of now.

Comment: No luck buddy, I tried both steps but for either of them I am getting same errors. For the first one when I install older versions it is throwing below warning when I run `firebase serve` - `Warning: This is a browser-targeted Firebase bundle but it appears it is being
>  run in a Node environment.  If running in a Node environment, make sure you
>  are using the bundle specified by the "main" field in package.json.` and with the 2nd approach it still throws the same error. Somehow it is not able to resolve the `path`.. :(

Comment: I have updated my post. Do you get any ideas from that as in what might be wrong?

Comment: Maybe if you go with the first option. I found someone who wrote this online: 'I solved issue with my ssr setup by making firebase depenencies "external" in firebase config for server bunding. Just add: externals: [/^firebase/] to your webpack config, and make sure that all dependencies are installed in functions folder (package).' Looks like it could solve your problem.

Comment: No issues bro.. I got it somehow.. Thanks for the help though..

Answer (score 0):

<strike>So, after days of investigation, I had to follow a dirty approach for the SPA to work in cloud functions as an SSR application.</strike>

As I mentioned in my last update on the post, I had to make `opts.fallback` as false for all the cases. I did this on being sure that `@google-cloud` will be there only for `functions` in my application. Now it looks something like below:

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
if (isBrowser) {
    opts.fallback = true;
}

opts.fallback = false; //Added this line.
```

Now, everything works fine. But, ultimately, this is the dirtiest approach.

I am still confused on certain things under `@google/cloud` as I noticed that there is also **`firestore_admin_client.js`** file and not really sure when this will get called. Also, I am worried if this approach causes any security loopholes in the future.

Anyways, I'll keep posted if anything I find in the future, upon debugging this.

Well, the above approach seems to fail when I deploy the function to cloud. This will only work in local with `firebase serve`